# Unable to modify python script in Windows

Tags: python, windows

I'm currently using *PyCharm* and *Sublime Text* in **Window** to develop some **Python** script, but this morning something quite strange happens.

I am changing my code and testing it by running my code over test input. It is supposed to change the output text quite a lot. The output text at the end did not change at all. Then I try commenting out my output function, simply pass through the reading script. I thought "Now it should print nothing". But it prints the same output as yesterday, as if I never modified it today.

Any suggestion?

---

It turns out it's because my colleague has pushed an unexpected change up to repo last night...I always pulled before I end the day. The text output was forced by his logger:)

Mystery solved! Thanks for reading guys.

Comment: Did you check the rights? Are you working with git or some version control system? Is there any change in your computer between yesterday and today?

Comment: I don't know how to check rights in Windows to be honest. I'm working with Mercurial, and I did not commit my change yet. I did not do any installation, uninstallation, or update in my Windows (at least not that I am aware of)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had exactly the same thing happen with Sublime. In my case I had moved / renamed the file after closing sublime. I reopened sublime some time later which reopened *the old version of the file* because I had left the file open when I last closed down sublime.

Have you tried closing the file and then opening it again *from windows* i.e. right-click => open with Sublime Text, to make sure you're editing the correct version?